# Highscores (top scores) rank calculation & update query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a high scoring (top scores) system, which is calculating positions by players's eperience.
But now I need to use the player's rank in other places just the web, maybe more places in the web too like personal
high scores, and it will show the player's rank in that skill.

Therefore just looping & playing with the loop cycle like rank++ won't really work, cause I need to save that rank for
other places.

What I could do is *loop* through all players and then send a query to update that player's rank, but what if i have `1000` players? or more?
that means `1000` queries per load.

I have thought if there could be a ***SQL query*** I can use to do the same action, in one or two queries.

How can I do this? I ***calculate ranks*** by ordering by player's eperience, so my *table* structure looks like this:

Tables:

- Players

  id (auto_increment) integer(255)

  displayname varchar(255) unique

  rank integer(255) default null

  experience bigint(255)

Comment: show the original tables structure from where you want to extract the rank, and the table where you have your users

Comment: @FilipeSilva Not sure which structure did you want, but I've edited it if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the rank for user with id = 1. If you want every player, just remove the WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.displayname, a.rank, a.experience
FROM (    
    SELECT id, displayname, @r:=@r+1 AS rank, experience
    FROM players, (SELECT @rank:=0) tmp
    ORDER BY experience DESC) a
WHERE a.id = 1
```

I wouldn't have rank in the players table directly, since this would mean that you would have to recalculate it every time a user changes experience. You could do this query anytime you want to get the rank for a player or for a leaderboard.

If you still want to update it, You can do an INNER JOIN with this query to UPDATE the original table with the rank from this query.

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't really work correctly. I have 2 users, 1 with 2147 xp and 1 with 5 xp, the one with 2147 xp is rank 2 and the other is rank 1?